# Regexreplace with ignore

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to regexreplace the number 2 in some rows with "double", but I want to ignore if the numbers are 12, 22, 32 etc.

[image]

EDIT:

What if I add letters to the numbers? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to tackle this, but using `^2$` will only match `2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,
   IF(
    REGEXMATCH(
     TO_TEXT(A1:A),
     "^2$"),
    "double",
    A1:A)))
```

Using REGEXMATCH instead of REGEXREPLACE allows us to return the values in A1:A as actual numerical values instead of the text value the formula requires.

Working with `a2` etc, this will allow for optional letters before the `2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,
   IF(
    REGEXMATCH(
     TO_TEXT(A1:A),
     "^(?i)[A-Z]+?2$"),
    "double",
    A1:A)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. What do I have to do if the numbers are with a piece of text? So for example: a2 a3 a6 a12. Is it possible to only replace the strings containing "2" and not "12"?

Comment: @Jelmer405 -- I added a second formula. It allows for optional letters before the number and is case insensitive.